# python if evaluating True for False value

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I have the following object field:

```
is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have the following if statement:

```
print(customer.is_vendor) //This prints False
if customer.is_vendor:
     print('im a vendor') //This prints even the value above is false

else:
     print('im not a vendor')
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: Just a guess (hence a comment), does `models.BooleanField` implement the [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__bool__#object.__bool__) method? What happens when you run `bool(is_vendor)`? If it doesn't implicitly have a truthy value you might need to be explicit in `if customer.is_vendor ==...` Again, just an educated guess.

Comment: You have a string in the field. Which is cool for django but not python.  Try `customer.is_vendor.to_python()` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You have a string in the field  -- "False" as opposed to False. Which is cool for Django but not python.  Try `customer.is_vendor.to_python()` instead. That will wrangle it into a boolean for you.

```
if "False": print 'True!' # is True
if False: print 'True!'   # Nope.

if customer.is_vendor.to_python():
   print "Is a vendor!"
```

Comment: but it is a django boolean field, why would it be a string?

Comment: Check the source -- The boolean field has a lose definition of boolean and does not wrangle the value by default.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#BooleanField

Comment: That's sure loose.